# Static resource not getting loaded at all

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

I had a compressed static resource file with lots of styling and javascript files. I just downloaded that file and re-uploaded again but after uploading it no styling and javascript is getting loaded.

I am really frustrated at this problem because not able to figure out the why is this happening for 2 hours

Static resource i uploaded with name : NewResource    MIME Type application/x-zip-compressed

My code :

```
<apex:page controller="NMAT_LoginContoller" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0" title="Register">     

  <head>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.NewResource, 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.NewResource, 'assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.NewResource, 'assets/css/chosen.min.css')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.NewResource, 'assets/styles/scss/style.scss')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.NewResource, 'assets/styles/scss/vars.scss')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.NewResource, 'assets/css/style.css.map')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.NewResource, 'assets/css/fonts.css')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.NewResource, 'assets/css/style.css')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.NewResource, 'assets/css/vars.css')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.NewResource, 'assets/css/vars.css.map')}"/>           
 </head>
```

Rest of vf page

Comment: Request you to share your code what you've tried...

Comment: did you clear your browser cache? is the file being loaded? do you have any errors in your console? is the file loading in your network tab...Please update your post accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Did you extract it and then compress again but compress at the wrong folder level?

Comment: Triple check the ZIP that you haven't introduced a folder at the root (before "assets").

Comment: You don't need to use `head` to include CSS via `apex:stylesheet`. This isn't the cause, but you should be aware that it is not necessary.

Comment: Dan Wooding was correct...i had my path wrong because of compression and decompression

Comment: @DanWooding you should add that as an answer so the OP can mark is as accepted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue where this became an issue. What you need to do instead of doing "Send To > Compressed (zipped) folder" on the folder, do it on the files inside the folder.

When you compress the folder itself, you end up with "foo.zip/foo/bar.js" instead of "foo.zip/bar.js".